# Injecting a JSON string with interpolated variable not working

Tags: php, json, interpolation, string-interpolation

I'm using the [Rocketium API](https://rocketium.com/docs/api#api-create-video) to auto generate videos.

To prepare the "scenes" used in the video, I built a JSON string from rows in a table of my database:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {

    if ($product['image_one_url']) {
        $product_image = $product['image_one_url'];
    } else {
        $product_image = 'no_image.png';
    }

    $string[] = [
        "text" => $product['product_name'],
        "image" => $product_image
    ];

}

$string = json_encode($string, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
$string = addslashes($string);
```

Here is how `$string` outputs:

```
[{\"text\":\"Definitions\",\"image\":\"vesa_definitions.jpg\"},{\"text\":\"Persona\",\"image\":\"vesa_persona.jpg\"},{\"text\":\"Universal Invitation\",\"image\":\"vesa_universal_invitation.jpg\"},{\"text\":\"Immortal\",\"image\":\"vesa_immortal.jpg\"},{\"text\":\"Birth\",\"image\":\"vesa_birth.jpg\"},{\"text\":\"Red Eye\",\"image\":\"vesa_red_eye.jpg\"},{\"text\":\"Lakshmi (Resurrection)\",\"image\":\"vesa_lakshmi.jpg\"},{\"text\":\"T(r)opical\",\"image\":\"vesa_tropical.jpg\"},{\"text\":\"Fork and Flip\",\"image\":\"vesa_fork_and_flip.jpg\"},{\"text\":\"Stereoscopic\",\"image\":\"vesa_stereoscopic.jpg\"},{\"text\":\"I AM SATOSHI NAKAMOTO\",\"image\":\"vesa_takeshi_nakamoto.jpg\"}]
```

Now I'm taking this string and trying to plug it in here with the interpolated variable:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"videoBackground\": \"background.jpg\", \"audio_mood\": \"inspirational\", \"logoImage\": \"logo.png\", \"title\": \"Products\", \"themeId\": \"5a15310cabc5e17e6bf29525\", \"scenes\": {$string}}");
```

This is not working for me for some reason, although when I compare my JSON string to a working example, it looks the same format:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"videoBackground\": \"background.jpg\", \"audio_mood\": \"inspirational\", \"logoImage\": \"logo.png\", \"title\": \"Products\", \"themeId\": \"5a15310cabc5e17e6bf29525\", \"scenes\": [{\"text\" : \"{Hello there\", \"image\" : \"https://rocketium.com/videos/1234567890/resized/abcdefgh.mp4\", \"fontSize\" : \"14px\"}, { \"text\" : \"Slide 2 goes here\", \"image\" : \"https://rocketium.com/videos/1234567890/resized/abcdefgh.mp4\" }, { \"text\" : \"Slide 3 here\", \"image\" : \"https://rocketium.com/videos/1234567890/resized/abcdefgh.mp4\" }, { \"text\" : \"Slide 4 here\", \"image\" : \"image_goes_here.jpg\" }]}");
```

I've added slashes and everything. Is this an issue with the interpolated variable or something else I'm missing?

Comment: Your `$string` variable declaration should have quotes around the value, as it should be a string. Other than that can you post the output of the rendered interpolated string to compare with the correct example you have already provided?

Comment: @mdexp I updated the OP to show how "$string" is built and what the output looks like. string might not be the best variable name I suppose since it starts as an array

Comment: Don't smash strings together to make JSON. [Parse the JSON into a data structure](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), manipulate it like regular data, then [generate JSON again](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: @Chris thanks im unclear what you mean though. Can you show me an example?

Comment: Can you explain more what it the error and how do you receive the request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to cram one string inside another, manually escaping quotes and hoping for the best, work with data structures and only convert to JSON when you're done.

Something like this:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {

    if ($product['image_one_url']) {
        $product_image = $product['image_one_url'];
    } else {
        $product_image = 'no_image.png';
    }

    $string[] = [
        "text" => $product['product_name'],
        "image" => $product_image
    ];

}

$template = json_decode("{\"videoBackground\": \"background.jpg\", \"audio_mood\": \"inspirational\", \"logoImage\": \"logo.png\", \"title\": \"Products\", \"themeId\": \"5a15310cabc5e17e6bf29525\"}");

$template['scenes'] = $string;

// Now you can encode the whole thing to JSON in one go
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($template));
```

Answer (score 2):

@chris is right, I'm just going to tell you why your code didn't work. Because **you actually injected extra backslashes** to the json string, while in the working example, there is no real backslashes(they just appear in the code to tell PHP that the next char is a double quotes not the closing one)

This string `"\""` contains just one double quote , while this string `'\"'` contains a backslash and a double quote

The scenes property in the working example is actually contains this

```
 $scenes = '[{"text":"Definitions","image":"vesa_definitions.jpg"}]';
```

But this is what you did by using `addslashes()`

```
 $scenes = '[{\"text\":\"Definitions\",\"image\":\"vesa_definitions.jpg\"}]';
```